# How can I prevent executing comman code outside if-else block?

Tags: javascript, angular

**page.ts**

```
//all imports are made correctly

       export class page{

            constructor(){}//used DI correctly.

              public someFunction(){

             let result: any;


                if(x = true){    
                   try{    
                     result = this.serviceClass.doSomething();    
                  }
                   catch(e){
                   //do some processing.
                  }    
                }
                 else{    
                    try {     
                      result = this.serviceClass.doAnotherThing();    
                     }
                    catch(e){    
                   //do some processing.    
                     }
                  }

                 console.log(result); //line 1
                 service2.oneThing(); ///line 2

                 //other tasks and common functions. //line 3    
           }
          }
```

**Question1**: In the above piece of code, How do I stop the execution of line 1, line 2 and line 3? When any of the try block catches the exception.

**Question2**: How can I use only one try-catch block for both if - else statements?That is if any exception is caught either in if or in else block only one try-catch block will do everything, and the common code does not execute i.e line 1 line 2 & line 3.

Comment: I suppose that the logic code is wrapped within a function.

Comment: ohh yes, i am sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `try` block arround both conditions, which will automatically jump to the `catch` block as soon as an error occurs.

In the following example I try to demonstrate this.

```js
function getResult1(shouldThrow){
  if (shouldThrow) throw new Error("FAILED TO GET RESULT 1");
  return 1;
}

function getResult2(shouldThrow){
  if (shouldThrow) throw new Error("FAILED TO GET RESULT 2");
  return 2;
}

function doIt(condition, shouldThrow){
  var result;
  try {
    if (condition){
      result = getResult1(shouldThrow);
    } else {
      result = getResult2(shouldThrow);
    }
    
    console.log("Successfully got result", result);
  
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('We ran into an error', e.toString());
  }
}  


for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   var shouldThrow = i % 2 == 0;
   var condition   = i > 2;
   console.log(`Trying condition = ${condition} and shouldThrow = ${shouldThrow}`);
   doIt(condition, shouldThrow);
   console.log("------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: Early return when an exception is caught in try block.

Answer 2: Use if/else in try block.

```
public someFunction(){

  let result;

  try {
    result = x ? this.serviceClass.doSomething() : this.serviceClass.doAnotherThing();

    console.log(result); //line 1
    service2.oneThing(); ///line 2

    //other tasks and common functions. //line 3  
  } catch(e) {

  }

}
```

Comment: Can't we write the console statements with the corresponding conditions?i.e) `result = x ? this.serviceClass.doSomething() : this.serviceClass.doAnotherThing();` when `this.serviceClass.doSomething()` executes then it will print console corresponding to this, and similary for the other?

Comment: Why are you recommending a ternary expression when an if statement makes more sense? also why wouldn't you just put the catch statement after the things you want to avoid? Try always jumps out of execution as soon as the first error is thrown.

Comment: Both answers work for me.I want to consider the one which will be best suited to my requirements.

Comment: @Mobius - a ternary operator is correct here. The intent is to assign a variable to `result`, not branch the execution, so you'd want to indicate that to the reader (maintainer). The if statement in your answer is actually a misuse of that construct.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I'm not saying that you _can't_ use a ternary for that, just that it is misleading to the OP, because it looks like the solution to putting a condition inside a try/catch block is to use a ternary, which is false.